# Is it possible to create fixed-size drawables in Android API pre-23?

Tags: android, android-drawable

This is a selector drawable for radiobutton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/ColorPrimaryDark" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <layer-list>
                    <item android:gravity="center_vertical|left" android:left="20dp">
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
                            <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="2dp" />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                    <item android:gravity="center_vertical|left" android:left="25dp">
                        <shape android:shape="oval">
                            <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" />
                            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                </layer-list>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/ColorPrimary" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:left="20dp">
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
                    <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="2dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In Android API 23 it looks like following (when applied):

[image: API 23]

In Android API 22, though, it looks like following:

[image: API 22]

Is there a way to define fixed size vector (ie. non-bitmap) drawable in API pre-23?

Answer (score 0):

Try the method below to scale the drawable programatically:

```
// Read your drawable from somewhere
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somedrawable);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
// Scale it to 100 x 100
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true));
// Set your new, scaled drawable "d"
```